# How does evolving relate to CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

What I mean is how does the game increase the CP of an evolving pokemon? 
For instance I have a pidgey (278CP) when I evolved it became a pidgeotto (489CP), but when I leveled up my weedle (140CP) it became kakuna (150CP).

With some pokemon it seems to be doubled, others tripled, and some not at all

Comment: Kakuna isn't a terribly strong Pokemon, so that probably accounts for the modest bump. Evolve that Kakuna, though, and I bet you see a pretty large leap in CP.

Comment: @Ellesedil Frankly OP should consider themself lucky it knows more than Harden.

Comment: when I evolve the Kakuna I got a 350CP Beedrill. Just kind of sucked because the Pidgeot I got was 840CP. Beedrill didn't even make it into my top 10

Comment: It would have been higher if Weedle had started higher. Start with a 278 Weedle and see what happens  :p

Comment: 140 has been the highest I've found and I'm lvl 16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's based on the level (the pokemon's progress on the semicircle) and the species. Level doesn't actually change on evolving, so this question is entirely about the species.

Kakuna and Metapod are renowned for being useless stages between weedle/caterpie and beedrill/butterfree. Consequently, a kakuna of any level is going to be fairly weak.